When using autoresizing mask layout. How do I satisfy the warnings?
I get this warning.

Views without any layout constraints may clip their content or overlap other views.

However, I am using autoresizing mask, I shouldn't need to use constraints. Is there something I am missing? When resizing to different views, it all works great.



So after tinkering around with it. If you change the layout: Infered(auto resizing mask) -> auto resizing mask. The warnings vanishes...
